# Sum the value of dictionarys in an array if keys has same value

Tags: flutter, dart

I've just learn dart recently.I have an array like this and want to sum the value if the value of name is the same.

```
var = array [{'name': 2010,'value':10},{'name': 2010,'value':20},{'name': 2011,'value':15},{'name': 2011,'value':40}];
```

I want to get an result like this

```
var array = [{'name': 2010,'value':30},{'name': 2011,'value':55}];
```

I can do this on javascript but don't know how to do this on dart.
My code on javascript:

```
let array = [{'name': 2010,'value':10},{'name': 2010,'value':20},{'name': 2011,'value':15},{'name': 2011,'value':40}],

    result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, {name, value}) => {
                      a[name] = (a[name] || {name, value: 0});
                      console.log('a[date]',a[name]);
                      a[name].value = String(Number(a[name].value) + Number(value));
                      console.log('a[dat',a);
                      return a;
                  }, {}));

              console.log(result);
```

Comment: `Iterable` has `reduce()` method too

Comment: Still, I don't know how to implement this. Can you show me the way how to do this?.

Comment: `var a = [{'name': 2010,'value':10},{'name': 2010,'value':20},{'name': 2011,'value':15},{'name': 2011,'value':40}];
  var map = {};
  a.forEach((elem) => map[elem['name']] = (map[elem['name']] ?? 0) + elem['value']);
  print(map);` - `forEach` is better imho - now you can convert result `map` into any format you want

Comment: for example: `print(map.entries.map((entry) => {entry.key: entry.value}).toList());`

Comment: Really nice mate. Thank you so much.

Comment: sure, your welcome